# Created csv from csv list based on column values Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm new in python and i 'm trying to sort and create csv file by the values of col 3 for which is row header

The csv as this following structure:

```
Name;Family;ID
Paul;Smith;5
Kery;Gou;6
Jimmy;Ja;2
Jony;Luo;5
Jack;Elve;2
```

The result i want to get is 3 different file (in this case) sort by the id

So file one Id5.csv should be like

```
Paul  Smith  5
Jony  Luo    5
```

File Id6.csv should be like

```
Kery  Gou    6
```

And Id2.csv should look like

```
Jimmy Ja     2
Jack  Elve   2
```

Hope i was clear, any help would be appreciate

Comment: What is your current data structure, you've not stated, is this `pandas` if so state this and add the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
with open('your.csv') as f:
    lines = [line.split(';') for line in f.read().splitlines()[1:]]

lines_grouped = [[l for l in lines if l[2]==x] for x in {l[2] for l in lines}]
for group in lines_grouped:
    with open('Id' + group[0][2] + '.csv', 'w+') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join([','.join(line) for line in group]))
```

Comment: Work perfectly ! Thanks you very much

Answer (score 2):

This can achieved easily using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library:

```
In [141]:
import pandas as pd
import io
#
t="""Name;Family;ID
Paul;Smith;5
Kery;Gou;6
Jimmy;Ja;2
Jony;Luo;5
Jack;Elve;2"""
#load the csv
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=';')
# now get unique IDs, construct a filename and write out
for ID in df['ID'].unique():
    print('ID' + str(ID))
    #df[df['ID']==ID].to_csv('ID' + str(ID) + '.csv')
ID5
ID6
ID2
```

You can ignore the `io` bit above in your case it would just be:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=';')
```

So you'd just uncomment line:

```
df[df['ID']==ID].to_csv('ID' + str(ID) + '.csv')
```

you can optionally pass params `index=False` and `sep='\t'` if you don't want an index column and you prefer tab separated, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_csv)

Comment: Thanks EdChum, is there a way to use the list as input created in a separated file?

Comment: Can you edit what your list looks like into your question, thanks